# Apps are crashing after changing SIM

Tags: applications, samsung, sim-card, crashes

I changed my service provider a day ago and after that almost all the apps are crashing. I deleted the cache factory stop etc. Nothing has worked. When I restart my phone I am able to use apps perfectly but after 10 or 20 minutes later it's same again. Hope you got something for me.

Comment: Such errors are hard to understand without a proper log. Therefore my recommendation is to enable developer mode on Android, then enable ADB, connect the phone to a PC with installed Android SDK or minimal ADb and then check what error is shown in `adb logcat` when the apps start crashing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.